# Browser closes automatically after script execution

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation

This following code runs without any errors, but it automatically closes Google Chrome after the script completes.

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

sev_obj = Service("C:\\Drivers\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q").send_keys("Selenium")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q").submit()

time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@href='https://www.selenium.dev/']//h3[@class='LC20lb MBeuO DKV0Md']["
                              "normalize-space()='Selenium']").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```

Add this before instantiating the driver, and that you can do with

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try commenting out the line that closes the browser to keep it open:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Initialize ChromeDriver and WebDriver
sev_obj = Service("C:/Drivers/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=sev_obj)

# Open Google, maximize window
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.maximize_window()

# Search for "Selenium"
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q").send_keys("Selenium")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q").submit()

# Wait and click on Selenium's official site
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@href='https://www.selenium.dev/']//h3[normalize-space()='Selenium']").click()

# Commenting out the line that closes the browser to keep it open
# driver.quit()
```